# Cloud Shell custom image for all users in the project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I have created a custom image for Google Cloud Shell, it works well with my user account, but not with other users in the same project. How can I set the image as the default for all users?

Comment: I have not used much the [Cloud Shell API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/cloudshell/v1alpha1/), but you could play around with it and see if there's any way to do what you want. However, I don't think environments on the Cloud Shell are linked to projects, but rather to users (as shown by the API definitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Shell custom image setting is per user. So you will need to update each individual user from the project to use the custom image created by you. You can ask other users from the project to use 'Cloud Shell Environment' UI to update the image setting. Hope that helps!

Comment: Where is the Cloud Shell custom image setting?